# Is multiple delete available in sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a multiple contentIds.

```
Mode.findAll({
    where: {
     id: contentIds
   }
  })
```

After finding all how can I Delete multiple rows from a table.

Or tell me other options to delete multiple records with a single query.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Example:

```
Model.destroy({ where: { id: [1,2,3,4] }})
```

For more details check the [API docs](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#static-method-destroy).

Comment: how to do for multiple column check  id, somecolumn ?

Comment: Might be worthy to consider the paranoid option: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62226425/5157706

Comment: The original link is dead, it seems that part has been reworked and there is no section for bulk delete in the guides anymore. I have linked the relevant API page instead.

Comment: Url is not working throwing 404

Comment: Working url: https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/model.js~model#static-method-destroy

Answer (score 45):

If you want to delete ALL models of a specific type, you can use:

```
Model.destroy({where: {}}).then(function () {});
```

This will delete all records of type 'Model' from database.
Tested with mysql;

Comment: Came here looking for a way to delete ALL records of a specific type. This worked perfectly!

Comment: `await Model.destroy({where: {}})`

Answer (score 12):

You can use destroy method on a model:

```js
Model.destroy({
  where: {
    id: contentIds
  }
});
```

For more details check the [API docs](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#static-method-destroy).

Comment: I am having mysql database. is this work on mysql ??

Comment: @SpunkyLive this does work in mySQL. I am on sequelize 2.0.3.

Comment: @Nikolay, your answer is actually more correct using the variable contentIds. Updated docs for anyone still interested in a mass delete: http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/instances/#destroying-deleting-persistent-instances

Comment: @js_gandalf cool, although others should keep in mind that you `cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint`, as I ran into on one of my tables. ;)

Comment: The original link is dead, it seems that part has been reworked and there is no section for bulk delete in the guides anymore. I have linked the relevant API page instead.

Comment: api docs link not working

Answer (score 5):

To destroy all entries in a model:

```
Model.destroy({
    where: {}
}).then(function(){
    console.log('destroy all data');
    res.redirect('/');
})
```

Comment: Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.

Answer (score 4):

Note that if you have [paranoid](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/paranoid.html) enabled, and you really want to destroy the rows from the table instead of just setting their `deleted_at` timestamp, pass the option `force: true` to the `Model.destroy({})` method.